# Wicket breadCrumb back button

Tags: wicket

I have a panel page where i show two breadcrumb links when a button is clicked from the page. I want to be able to go back to the same page on back button. for example, I am in panel page "Group" and  when a button is clicked on the Group page, two breadcrumbs will be shown
Group>>item >> application. 
I want to go back to group page from application page when clicking a back button.

```
public class GroupPanel extends Panel
{

private final IBreadCrumModel breadCrumbModel;


public GroupPanel(String id, final IBreadCrumbModel breadCrumbModel)
{
    super(id);
    this.breadCrumbModel = breadCrumbModel;
    addGroup();
}

public void addGroup()
{

    add(new ListView<GroupDetails>("rows", listData)
    {
        public void populateItem(final ListItem<GroupDetails> item)
        {
            item.add(new WebMarkupContainer("view")
            {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public boolean isVisible()
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }.add(new BreadCrumbLink<Void>("action", breadCrumbModel)
            {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public IBreadCrumbParticipant getBreadCrumbParticipant()
                {
                    breadCrumbModel.setActive(new ItemPanel(breadCrumbModel, ItemModel));// adding
                                                                                            // two
                                                                                            // breadcrumbs
                    return new ApplicationPanel(breadCrumbModel, ApplicationModel);

                }
            }));
        }
    });

}
```

}

```
public class ApplicationPanel extends BreadCrumbPanel
{

private IBreadCrumbParticipant breadCrumbReturn

public ApplicationPanel(final IBreadCrumbModel breadCrumbModel, IModel<Application> ApplicationModel){
    this(breadCrumbModel.getActive().getComponent().getId(), breadCrumbModel, ApplicationModel)
}

public ApplicationPanel(String id, final IBreadCrumbModel breadCrumbModel, IModel<Application> ApplicationModel){
    super(id, breadCrumbModel)
    setBreadCrumbModel(breadcrumbs.getActive())
}

@Override
protected void onInitialize() {
    super.onInitialize()
    form = new Form<Void>("form"){
    add(form);

    addBackButton();
}

public void setBreadCrumbReturn(IBreadCrumbParticipant breadCrumbReturn)
{
    this.breadCrumbReturn = breadCrumbReturn;
}

protected void addBackButton(){

    form.add(new BreadCrumbLink<Void>("back", getBreadCrumbModel()) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public IBreadCrumbParticipant getBreadCrumbParticipant() {
            return breadCrumbReturn;    
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isVisible() {
            return true
        }
    }); 
}

/**
 * @see org.apache.wicket.extensions.breadcrumb.IBreadCrumbParticipant#getTitle()
 */
public String getTitle()
{
    return "Application";
}
```

}

```
public class Item extends BreadCrumbPanel{

public Item(IBreadCrumbModel breadCrumbModel, final IModel<Item> itemModel){
    super(breadCrumbModel.getActive().getComponent().getId(), breadCrumbModel)
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using `BreadCrumbPanel`? Maybe show some code?

Comment: I have edited it to include the sample code and yes i am using breadcrumbPanel

Comment: Sorry I have a hard time understanding what you want to achieve. I can see you have groups displayed as rows, but that do you want to do with them?

Comment: what i am trying to do is, when a link is clicked from group page, i am adding two breadcrumbs( item and application) and when a back button( take a look at addBackButton() method)  gets clicked from application page, i want to go back to group page. right now the back button i have takes me back to item page